# IT Assistant salary for college student

Tags: untagged

How much should a person working as an IT Assistant doing intranet development on drupal and anything else needed to be done with the computers/network at any of our five locations supporting ~150 employees.

I have a total of about 3 years real experience in IT and am a sophomore in college taking CS classes.

I'm discussing the a raise tomorrow with my boss and the HR manager, I live in Michigan and am making 9.50 an hour working there now working 35-35hrs a week with no benefits.

Am I getting screwed with that salary? How much should I ask for tomorrow and is there anything I can reference to show them I am being underpaid, if I am?

Comment: This is off-topic for the site, since salary is very localized and specific to the person and job.  It might be best to ask some people locally, perhaps take a look the help wanted ads and see if anyone is advertising a similar position, and if they are ask them how much they are paying.  Also check out some of the common salary survey sites like salary.com  I suspect you may be underpaid.

Comment: Payscale.com will probably be more use.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be to take the $9.50 an hour and be happy with it. You're essentially getting a paid internship while you're going to school. Granted you're working a lot of hours (but far less than most of the rest of us in IT work) but where else are you going to get a salary plus experience while basically having your employer teach you how to do the job that you're studying for a career in?

Ahhh... To be young and making $9.50 an hour and only working 30 hours a week while my boss helps launch me in to my career... (Sigh)

Comment: You're right the experience is invaluable but I would like to move out and have at least some extra spending money.

Answer (score 1):

College students are generally paid pennies on what their job is worth because of the absurd amount of candidates available. Bring all the reasons you can for a raise (Salary.com would help with an average for your area), but don't be too disappointed if you get a "Take it or leave it" answer.

Comment: I honestly think they would have a hard time replacing me. Most of the people I know around here in the field make 14-20 an hr. Granted they are different jobs but same field and similar work. I do a lot of drupal development for them also. We will see, I am going to ask for 12.50